# Return arguments being sent to a Mockery mocked function?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, mockery

I'm rather new to the PHP Mockery framework, and attempting to test multiple functions on a mocked service request function. The different functions send the same variable names with different values. I'd like to test to make sure each case is hitting the mocked class. Can I receive multiple arguments with my mocked function and return each of them to the tester function?

The function to test:

```
    public function doSomething() {
    $result = $this->serviceRequest('stuff', '/url', []);
    return $result;
}
```

The pseudocode for testing function:

```
public function testDoSomething() {

    $service_mock = $this->mockService();
    $this->assertEquals($service_mock->doSomething(), $returnedArgs);
}
```

I'd ideally like to take those three arguments being sent to the mock, return them with the mock's `andReturn()` or something similar to be asserted in the original test method (to verify they are being sent to the mock).  Is there a good way to do this or a common practice I'm missing?

Right now, my mock is looking similar to this pseudocode (and those 3 arguments are being validated in closure `$args`):

```
        $client->shouldReceive('serviceRequest')->withArgs($args)->once()->andReturnUsing($args)->getMock();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a callback to do this:
The below example is adapted form the Mockery docs, although it uses it as an example for reference passing, it can be used for any custom expectations.

```
   $m->shouldReceive('insert')->with(
    \Mockery::on(function(&$data) use($logger) {
        if (!is_array($data)) return false;
        $data['_id'] = 123;
        $logger->logParameters('insert', $data);
        return true;
    }),
    \Mockery::any()
);
```

http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/pass_by_reference_behaviours.htm

Comment: If you need to mock something that returns values based on the arguments and not just test that the arguments are what you expect remember `andReturnUsing()` does accept a closure like the asker mentioned. It's passed the arguments that were given to the method.